# Is there a performance difference between == and > or < operations in java specifically

Tags: java

Is there a performance difference between **==** and **>** / **<** operations in java specifically.

I have already read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178761/is-there-any-performance-difference-between-greater-than-and-greater-than-or-equ), but it doesn't say in terms of java nor the comparison is in between similar operands.

Comment: It depends a fair bit on the type.

Comment: What do you mean by "comparison is in between similar operands." ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178761/is-there-any-performance-difference-between-greater-than-and-greater-than-or-equ In the above link, its about > and >=, so there might not be much difference. But when it comes to == and > or == and <, would there be a difference is my question.

Answer (score 2):

As [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029992/is-the-inequality-operator-faster-than-the-equality-operator) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861222/comparison-operator-performance) already [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178761/is-there-any-performance-difference-between-greater-than-and-greater-than-or-equ), the operators (and all instructions) are converted to machine-understable language (usually, [Assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_(programming)) or [Byte code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Byte_Code) work as a middle: your code is translated to those, then to binary. However, I'm not really working at/used to this level of programming. Feel free to correct me if I'm missing some point / machine language.)

Java compiles its classes to Byte code, which is then translated to machine code (binary) to perform hardware operations and computations. You can even [look the byte code by yourself](https://www.beyondjava.net/java-programmers-guide-java-byte-code), if it is really needed.

---

Considering the operators themselves, practically any microprocessor nowadays is able to optimize and make this kind of operations nearly instantaneous. If there was any difference between `==` and `> / <` in terms of performance, it would be in the order of mere nanoseconds, being Java, C++ or any compiled language. I am not even sure you could perform "in-code" metrics about this level of performance, considering Java, coupled with hardware, [won't always be able to give you precise time measurement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500911/precise-time-measurement-in-java) when it comes to nanoseconds.